# Removing character from array using strchr, does not return right value in plain C

Tags: c, string, char, return-value, strstr

I am trying to remove first semicolon from a character arrary whose value is:

> Input:  
> ; Test: 876033074,  808989746,  825766962, ; Test1:
>   825766962,

Code:

```
 char *cleaned = cleanResult(result);
            printf("Returned BY CLEAN: %s\n",cleaned);



    char *cleanResult(char *in)
    {   
        printf("Cleaning this: %s\n",in);

        char *firstOccur = strchr(in,';');
        printf("CLEAN To Remove: %s\n",firstOccur);
        char *restOfArray = firstOccur + 2;
        printf("CLEAN To Remove: %s\n",restOfArray); //Correct Value Printed here

        char *toRemove;
        while ((toRemove = strstr(restOfArray + 2,", ;"))!=NULL) 
        {
            printf("To Remove: %s\n",toRemove);
            memmove (toRemove, toRemove + 2, strlen(toRemove + 2));
            printf("Removed: %s\n",toRemove); //Correct Value Printed
        }

        return in;
    }
```

> Output (first semicolon still there):  
> ; Test: 876033074, 
>   808989746,  825766962; Test1: 825766962;

Comment: I removed the C++ tag because the C++ answer would involve totally rewriting your function.

Comment: if `result` and `cleaned` are the same thing, why copying one over the other?

Comment: At the time I'm posting this, the first section of code is strchr()ing ';', but NOT doing a memmove() to eliminate the "; " at the beginning of the line.  (You should probably be strstr()ing "; " instead of only searching for ';'.)  See Chris Dodd's answer regarding the second section of code that eliminates ", ;" or ", " (it's not clear what your intention is).  I don't understand why the final character of the input string, ',', is replaced by ';' in the output string; nothing in your code does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `sizeof(cleaned)`: using `sizeof` to get the capacity of an array only works if the argument is an array, not a pointer:

```
char buffer[100];
const char *pointer = "something something dark side";

// Prints 100
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(buffer));

// Prints size of pointer itself, usually 4 or 8
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(pointer));
```

Although both a local array and a pointer can be subscripted, they behave differently when it comes to `sizeof`.  Thus, you cannot determine the capacity of an array given only a pointer to it.

Also, bear this in mind:

```
void foo(char not_really_an_array[100])
{
    // Prints size of pointer!
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(not_really_an_array));

    // Compiles, since not_really_an_array is a regular pointer
    not_really_an_array++;
}
```

Although `not_really_an_array` is declared like an array, it is a function parameter, so is actually a pointer.  It is exactly the same as:

```
void foo(char *not_really_an_array)
{
...
```

Not really logical, but we're stuck with it.

---

On to your question.  I'm unclear on what you're trying to do.  Simply removing the first character of a string (in-place) can be accomplished with a memmove:

```
memmove( buffer             // destination
       , buffer + 1         // source
       , strlen(buffer) - 1 // number of bytes to copy
       );
```

This takes linear time, and assumes `buffer` does not contain an empty string.

The reason `strcpy(buffer, buffer + 1)` won't do is because the strings overlap, so this yields undefined behavior.  `memmove`, however, explicitly allows the source and destination to overlap.

For more complex character filtering, you should consider traversing the string manually, using a "read" pointer and a "write" pointer.  Just make sure the write pointer does not get ahead of the read pointer, so the string won't be clobbered while it is read.

```
void remove_semicolons(char *buffer)
{
    const char  *r = buffer;
    char        *w = buffer;

    for (; *r != '\0'; r++)
    {
        if (*r != ';')
            *w++ = *r;
    }

    *w = 0; // Terminate the string at its new length
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using strcpy with overlapping input / output buffer, which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You either use two buffers, one with original string, one with cleaned string, or you can write your own version of strcpy that safely handles overlapping input/output buffer

Comment: What about memmove() - thats fine with overlaps

Comment: @AdrianCornish, yes memmove is a good choice for overlapping buffers.

Comment: While memcpy might work, it's not a good solution.  Memcpy is not guaranteed to work with overlapping buffers and should not be used in such cases.  That's really what memmove is for.

Answer (score -1):

You're searching for a sequence of three characters (comma space semicolon) and then removing the first two (the comma and the space).  If you want to remove the semicolon too, you need to remove all three characters (use `toRemove+3` instead of `toRemove+2`).  You also need to add 1 to the strlen result to account for the NUL byte terminating the string.

If, as you say, you just want to remove the first semicolon and nothing else, you need to search for just the semicolon (which you can do with `strchr`):

```
if ((toRemove = strchr(in, ';'))    // find a semicolon
    memmove(toRemove, toRemove+1, strlen(toRemove+1)+1);  // remove 1 char at that position
```

Comment: -1 as i have said above I am trying to remove "first" semicolon only

Comment: @jaminator: in that case, why are you searching for a comma?  Maybe if you say what it is (exactly) you want to do, someone can help you.  What does strchr have to do with anything?

Comment: clarification in my prev comment. I am trying to remove  "first" semicolon & first two characters of each substing ", ;". and to be clear not all semicolons. Appreciate you answer though.